# Warning users if disabled library features are used in a C++ template library

Tags: c++, cross-platform, cmake, c-preprocessor

We have a C++ template library that has some features that depend on zlib, for example.
We selectively enable and disable features using preprocessor symbols, i.e. setting `-DHAVE_ZLIB=1` on the command line.

Our CMake-based build system recognizes installed zlib and adds the according flag to the compiler.
Of course, this can also be done manually by users, using their favourite IDE or their Makefiles.

One property of the library is that the code that uses zlib is interleaved with the code not using zlib, i.e. using `#include <library/header.h>` should work regardless of zlib being present or not.

Currently, we `#if` out code that depends on zlib.
Thus, if the user tries to use something like `CompressedStream`, for example, the class is simply not found.
This is quite frustrating for users.
The build system warns them that zlib could not be found, but users being users either do not see this or forget it quickly.
I myself have fallen into this trap, too.

Now to my question:
What is the best way to warn the user that zlib is disable if he tries to use code requiring zlib.

The only thing I can think of is using the deprecator marker mechanisms implemented in many compilers.
Although different syntax is required for each of them, this could easily be abstracted away using preprocessor macros.
Is there any other good way?

The solution only has to work in VS >8, GCC >4.2 and LLVM.

Comment: Can't you simply check for a preprocessor symbol (which is unlikely to change) of zlib and issue an `#error` if `HAVE_ZLIB==1`, but this symbol is undefined?

Comment: @sbi: That would detect an incorrect use of `HAVE_ZLIB`, but this is not what the OP wants: instead of completely removing a class if zlib is not there, he would like to keep the class but warn the user when he tries to use it.

Comment: @LucTouraille: Oh, I must have misread then. Sorry.

Comment: Why not add a dummy class (or default template specialization) which prints a warning? You can then switch with #ifdefs between the zlib-enabled version and the dummy class. Is this sufficient, or are there more requirements?

Comment: @Andre How would you issue the warning only when the class is used?

Comment: At runtime, with a simple std::cout << "Warning: ZLib unsupported." << std::endl;

Comment: At compile-time with some ifdef magic and the #warning macro or #pragma message.

Comment: @Andre Do you have a working solution for triggering a compiler warning only when the class is used? I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Comment: @Luc: No nothing working, except a possible apporach, but I am not sure if it will be sufficient for Manuel's problem. I propose to rewrite the class such that the "important" parts are placed into their own private implementation and then replace this with a dummy implementation at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper place to warn users about such things is (IMO) build system. Take a look at Ogre3D, KDE and many other projects - all of them print sort of outline after configuration of build. This outline contains information on what is found and what is not and what are consequences of this.

Even Qt don't do anyting to fix this. There is option to build Qt with STL support and if it's not built such way, there are no warnings or whatever, only compile errors regarding undefined methods. So, i think, there is no way to warn user about such things during compile phase.